# Add an extra step to column in javascript game

Tags: javascript

I created this arcade game by going through a few different tutorials and now I can't seem to finish it. I need to add an extra step so the player only wins when it steps into the water. At the moment the player wins when they step onto the final block.

Any direction would be appreciated, https://github.com/CathyXXX/Arcade-Game

Comment: Could you please be so kind and post the code where the player wins? Or even better just look through the code and add the event listener, or whatever it is, to the water (remove it from the final block) and it should work... if the game engine allows it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Check to see if the character reached the river
    if(this.y === 55) {
        this.gameover = true;
    }
```

This part of your code checks to see where the player's position is, and determines whether the player has progressed enough to win the game. This is the part you will want to edit so that the player "wins" the game when the player reaches the river, not the last tile.

The actual value you have to edit has been left as an exercise for the reader :)